# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'--React Native

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

Utilice este código para visualizar los datos atravez de un php que convierte una consulta a json

Codigo php para trasformar a json

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Galeria";
 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 
 
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 
 $tem = $row;
 
 $json = json_encode($tem);
 
 
 }
 
} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

código para visualizar los datos

```
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://proyectosabor2.tonohost.com/ver.php")    
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
      this.setState({
       dataSource: responseJson
      })
    })
```

Ya lo había utilizado y no me había dado problemas pero ahora me manda el siguiente error
JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo dos problemas en tu código:

1. Cuando en el cliente esperas un JSON, **toda respuesta del servidor debe ser un JSON**. No estás respetando eso en el caso de errores. Estás mandando un cadena sin más. Así no podrás comprobbar errores fácilmente y no estarás emitiendo un JSON, que es lo qu el cliente espera. Generalmente lo que se hace para los errores es crear un array con algo así más o menos: `'error'=>'Mensaje de error'`.
2. El  `while` está mal. No puedes poner esto: `$row[]` en las condiciones del `while`. Eso es incorrecto (ver código con la solución).

### PHP

```
<?php
    include 'conexion.php';
     
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    
    #Simplificamos, si no hay conexion el objeto será false 
    if (!$conn) {
        $json=array("error"=>"Error de conexión");
    }else{ 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Galeria";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows >0) {
            $json=array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                #El [] aquí, no en la cabecera del while
                $json[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            $json=array("error"=>"No Results Found.");
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
    #Conviene poner un header y un charset  
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    #Pase lo que pase, el cliente recibirá un JSON
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

### JS

Si observas, cuando hay errores, hemos puesto una clave `error` en la respuesta. Entonces en JS puedes, si quieres, hacer una verificación así:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://proyectosabor2.tonohost.com/ver.php")    
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
      if (response.error) {
          /*Ocurrió uno de los errores controlados hacer algo*/
      } else {
          this.setState({
           dataSource: responseJson
          })
     }
    })
```

Así se garantiza que `dataSource` no trate de llenarse cuando no han venido datos del servidor.